# client request for webpack bundle (php backend)

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I want to use just a script tag into the head of page the page.
The response should be a bundle (containing javascript files) which must be crated based on some changing options. 
Can this be done using webpack (how)?
At the back end php is used in case this matters

Comment: what are your need? I mean, why do you need to do that?

Comment: my task is to reduce script tags per page to one by using javascript modules

Comment: This is what webpack does. You simply have a single script to import all script to. Then use that script as the webpack bundle entry point.

Comment: yes that was what I thought but how can I modify that bundles every time by clients request?

Comment: You should not do that. The bundle should only include all the program logics. Any data that require changes should be loaded by AJAX calls by javascript.

Comment: well options specify which js files are going to be included into the bandle